Is there a closed form for all multiplicative operators on square real matrices?
Can we find a closed form for all $f: \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R$ such that for any square matrices $A$ and $B$ (both of order $n \times n$) we have:
$$f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$$
We know for example that the determinant of a matrix is such an operator.
But how much more can we know about those operators given this simple relation?
I function equations, a real function given by the rule $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ is well known on at least any rational number. How strong is this restriction on the domain of square real matrices?
I thought about doing the same we do on the functional equation:
by induction
$$f(\prod_{i=1}^n A_i) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(A_i)$$
but I guess the analogy ends up there, as we don't always have the square root of a matrix (as far as I know). We know that $f(I) = 1$ or $f \equiv 0$. It is also easy to see that if $f$ and $g$ satisfy this relation, then $fg$ will do so too.

Some observations: conjugation invariance should imply that it's a function of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. Either $f$ is constant $1$ or $f(0) = 0 \implies f(A) = 0$ for $A$ nilpotent.

An example is $f(A) = 1$ for invertible matrices and $f(A) = 0$ for singular matrices

@ronno actually, matrices with same characteristic polynomial may not be similar, so it may depend by more than that

and there are also $f(A) = g(det(A))$ where $g$ is multiplicative on the real numbers, for examples $g(x) = x^n$

@Exodd Right, I guess I was assuming something like continuity. Note however that $g(\det A)$, or characteristic function of ${\det A \ne 0}$ are (multiplicative) functions of the determinant, in particular of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial.

the key idea is $f$ is a class function.  Use Polar Form... this implies $f$ is a symmetric function of the eigenvalues of a PSD matrix [singular values of original matrix].  Evaluate on Householder matrices to get $O_n(\mathbb R)$ behavior [again $f$ symmetric function of eigenvalues].  Note the above implies $\det\big(A\big)=0\implies f\big(A\big)^n=0\implies f\big(A\big)=0$ so it's enough to focus on matrices $\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ [I believe it should also show $f$ is in the ideal generated by the determinant]

@user8675309 one can prove easily that $f(Q)$ is $0$, $1$ or $-1$ for any orthogonal $Q$, so you need also to take it into account

@Exodd -- that's baked into my comment since Householder matrices are involutions

yes, @user8675309 I meant for the polar decomposition, $f(QS) = \pm f(S)$

Ok, with a trick I can prove that $f(A) = g(det(A))$ when $A$ has at least 2 different singular values, with $g$ multiplicative on the real line

@user8675309 see the link above. All multiplicative measurable functions are of the form $g(det A)$

@Exodd So all of them are of the form $\det(A)^n$ for some real $n$?
